How to disable pinch zoom but allow pan with CSS
I am working on a PWA, in which I want to disable pinch zoom on the whole UI and only allow it on certain elements within the page.
Relevant CSS:
* {
    touch-action: pan-y;
}

Not sure if relevant HTML:
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />

The problem is that I can still zoom the whole page on my phone.
How can I fix this?

So, the problem was that I tested my PWA with Samsung Internet, which has an accessibility option to ignore the scale instructions and always enable pinch zoom. After turning it off and using the proper viewport settings, it seems to work fine.
Other browsers may have the same option, so I need to test it further.
Complete code:
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />

* {
    touch-action: pan-y;
}

